# Should I commit auto generated files published in npm package

Tags: git, typescript, npm, version-control, npmignore

I have a NPM package written in TypeScript. My build process takes all *.ts files and bundle them into myLib.d.ts, myLib.js and myLib.js.map.

My NPM package must have all src/*.ts files and these three myLib.* auto generated files.

But in my git repository, should I commit these three myLib.* auto generated files?

Is it a problem to publish files in npm package that are not under version control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output/generated files `myLib.d.ts`, `myLib.js` and `myLib.js.map` shouldn’t managed in git repo.

You should ignore these files by `.gitignore`. And it won’t effect to publish npm pakeages.

You can also refer the example [.gitignore](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/.gitignore) file for TypeScript.